# Color picker with multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, color-picker

Is there a plugin that can handle many colors selection?

I know about this one: https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#options-showSelectionPalette

However when I want to get all colors by doing

```
$("#showPalette").spectrum("get").toHexString();
```

it gives me only one color value.

Comment: what do you mean by all colors? When you have multiple spectrum widgets on the page?

Comment: It's called "palette" here: https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#options-showSelectionPalette